# broken yum/python

Tags: yum, python

Yum seems to be broken and below is the error.

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.2 (r262:71600, May 12 2009, 15:34:31)
[GCC 4.1.1]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

python -V gives the below output

```
Python 2.6.2
```

I only have python 2.6.6 installed, i am not sure why it's stating as 2.6.2

```
rpm -qa |grep python
```

lists only python 2.6.6, but still "python -V" says the version as 2.6.2

I even removed /usr/bin/python file and re-installed python-2.6.6, python-libs-2.6.6 and python-devel-2.6.6 which has recreated /usr/bin/python, but still

```
/usr/bin/python -V
```

gives output as Python 2.6.2

And exactly because of this, yum is broken

Comment: I suggest running `rpm -V -a` to see more precisely what's broken.

Comment: My initial guess is...a lot...